# cp some files from folder to folder

Tags: bash, find

I try to copy some files from a folder to another. I want to copy all them except some that begins with the same pattern, quality*.csv. I use the next code but it doesn't run.

```
#!/bin/bash 

dir=/home/meteo/data 
dir1=/home/meteo/data2
cd $dir
find . ! -name qualitat*.csv cp $dir1
```

what is wrong? thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-exec` option in `find`:

```
find . -type f ! -name "qualitat*.csv" -exec cp '{}' "$dir1" \;
```

OR using `xargs`:

```
find . -type f ! -name "qualitat*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 cp {} "$dir1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, which one is safer?